# How is this integration performed

Tags: integration

The signal intensity, $I_s$, at a distance $z$ in an optical fibre with Raman pumping is given by:

$$\frac{dI_{s}}{dz}=g_{R}I_{s}I_{p}$$

where $I_p$ is the pump intensity, $g_{R}$ is the raman gain co-efficient, and $z$ is the distance along the fibre.  Show that the solution to this equation is:

$$I_{s}(z)=I_{s}(0)exp(g_{R}I_{p}z)$$

I am sure this is a simple one liner, I assume I just need to integrate each side with respect to $z$, but I don't understand where the exponential is coming from?  Could someone explain how this result is achieved please?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac1{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} \log{y}$$

Comment: thanks: but playing with that I don't seem to be getting anywhere, although my math is terrible ... $$\frac{1}{I_{s}}\frac{dI_{s}}{dz}=g_{R}I_{p}=\frac{d}{dz}log(I_{s})=\frac{I_{s}'(z)}{I_{s}(z)}=\frac{g_{R}I_{s}I_{p}}{I_{s}(z)}$$  Is that formula something that has a name btw?

Comment: $\frac{1}{I_s} \frac{dI_s}{dz} = g_R I_p$, now move over the $dz$ and integrate.

Comment: Thank you, I get

$$\int g_{R}I_{p} dz = g_{R}I_{p}z = log(I_{s})$$

$$I_{s}=exp(g_{R}I_{p}z)$$

But I am not sure where the $I(0)$ comes from

Comment: When you perform that integral you need to add a constant $K$, when you then take the exponential you get $I_s(z)=exp(gRI_pz+K)=exp(K)exp(gRI_pz)$. You then set $z=0$ to find the constant.